# Specify directory for Serilog rolling file path

Tags: windows-services, serilog

Consider this app.config `appSetting` entry:

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat"
 value="ServerServiceApp-{Date}.log" />
```

This is done at app startup:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
    .Enrich.WithThreadId()
    .CreateLogger();
```

This is in a Windows service app. The log file ends up here:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64
```

Clearly, we’d rather have the log file end up in the same directory that houses this service’s .exe (customers don’t want us writing stuff to SysWOW64). But how?

We need the ReadFrom.AppSettings in there so that the customer can supply serilog settings in the app.config, as necessary.

Is there some way to change the directory used for the log file after the ReadFrom.AppSettings has been done?

Would be awesome if we could say something like:

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat"
 value="{ApDomainBaseDirectory}\ServerServiceApp-{Date}.log" />
```

(And where is {Date}, which can be put in the file path, documented?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best place for services to write their logs is `%PROGRAMDATA%` which, by default, is in `C:\ProgramData\`.

Try:

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat"
     value="%PROGRAMDATA%\ServerService\Logs\log-{Date}.txt" />
```

(`Program Files` is usually considered to be read-only, and writing stuff here will lead to oddities being left behind unexpectedly during uninstall.)

Comment: That idea will work perfectly. Didn't realize that environment variables could be put in the path string.

Comment: What if I prefer to locate my log files in a sub-folder of the deploy directory ( = runtime directory ) ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me with .Net 6 on Linux.  On Windows `%COMPUTERNAME%` gets nicely substituted. `${HOSTNAME}` results in `'${HOSTNAME}'` on Linux.

Answer (score 10):

Just put this before the creation of LoggerConfiguration:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Then `File.path` will be constructed based on the project root path.

Comment: It is great hack! When I used Serialog for writing to file in .NET5 I had the problem, logs files was created in root folder, not in "...\bin\Debug\net5.0", but when I had used your code it was helped.

Comment: This was the solution for me when running a console app using SQL Server Agent.